# "make test" more verbose in Perl

Tags: perl, automated-tests, cpan

When I run `make test` using the normal test harness that CPAN modules have, it will just output a brief summary (if all went well).

```
t/000_basic.t .......................... ok   
t/001_db_handle.t ...................... ok     
t/002_dr_handle.t ...................... ok     
t/003_db_can_connect.t ................. ok   
... snip ...
All tests successful.
Files=30, Tests=606,  2 wallclock secs 
Result: PASS
```

If I run the tests individually, they output much more detailed information.

```
1..7
ok 1 - use DBIx::ProcedureCall::PostgreSQL;
ok 2 - simple call to current_time
ok 3 - call to power() with positional parameters
ok 4 - call to power() using the run() interface
ok 5 - call to setseed with a named parameter
ok 6 - call a table function
ok 7 - call a table function and fetch
```

How can I run all the tests in this verbose mode? Is there something that I can pass to `make test`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) docs explain this in the [make test](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#make_test) section:

```
make test TEST_VERBOSE=1
```

If the distribution uses [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild), it's a bit different:

```
./Build test verbose=1
```

You can also use the [prove](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?prove) command that comes with [Test-Harness](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/):

```
prove -bv
```

(or `prove --blib --verbose` if you prefer long options.)  This command is a bit different, because it does *not* build the module first.  The `--blib` option causes it to look for the built-but-uninstalled module created by `make` or `./Build`, but if you forgot to rebuild the module after changing something, it will run the tests against the previously-built copy.  If you haven't built the module at all, it will test the installed version of the module instead.

[prove](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?prove) also lets you run only a specific test or tests:

```
prove -bv t/failing.t
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `prove` command:

```
prove --blib --verbose
```

from the unpacked module's top directory.  --blib includes the needed directories for a built but not installed module distribution.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty. It also highlights what I was specifically looking for (skipped tests).